# Decide whether integral series is finite

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to decide whether $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{[-1,1]^2} \left(1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^{n/2}\lambda_2(d(x,y))$$ 
is finite or not. $\lambda_2 = 2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.
Attempt:

Since $\left(1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^{n/2}$ is monotone in $n$, by monotone convergence we may exchange sum and integral to get $$\int_{[-1,1]^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^{n/2} \lambda_2(d(x,y))$$
Since $\left(1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^{n/2} < 1$ almost everywhere we have a geometric series:
$$\int_{[-1,1]^2}\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}} \lambda_2(d(x,y))$$
but I don't know if this leads my anywhere. Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Is that $\;\lambda_2\;$ some notation we should know...?

Comment: 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 1):

Idea: changing to polar coordinates, the integrand will be
$$\frac{r}{1 - \sqrt{1 - r^2/2}},$$
with elementary primitive.
Integration limits of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ in polar coordinates are awkward but feasible...

Comment: I could estimate it by $B^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb R^2 : \lVert z \rVert_2 \leq 1\}$? I assume it is $\infty$ so I can say $\int_{[-1,1]\times [-1,1]} \geq \int_{B_1}$...

Comment: @Staki42, good idea, try it.